# Scrypt Hashing algorithm behaves differently in PHP 7.2 and PHP 7.3

Tags: php, algorithm, hash, php-7.3, scrypt

I am trying to upgrade the PHP version from 7.2.25 to 7.3.21 version, after upgrade of PHP to 7.3.21 and Scyprt DLL, Scyrpt hash algorithm stopped working, user is not able to login, when tried to get into the root cause found that in PHP 7.3.21 hash is different from PHP 7.2.25 whereas parameter passed are same.

Used parameters are same for 7.2.x and 7.3.x where CPU - 1024, Memory - 8, Parallelization - 16

Comment: I am also facing the same issue and still no luck. We are now thinking of replacing the Scrypt hashing algorithm with some other algorithm

Comment: Is there any alternative for scrypt in php?